# 4G Mobile Router with API

Tags: router, 4g

I'm looking for a 4G router that has SMS features I can access programmatically via an API, e.g. to send and receive SMS etc.

The nearest I have found so far is a Huaweii router that I can access the control panel of using a fake browser interface, i.e. front-end scraping.

I would rather not use a Huaweii though.

Comment: Will this router connect only as a WiFi Access Point, and/or should it have one or more Ethernet ports?

Comment: It should ideally be a WiFi access point, and Ethernet ports would be ideal although not vital.